# Should I perform linear regression multiple times to train my dataset?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, cross-validation

I am working on Boston data set from MASS library. I separated the training and test data (70 / 30)

In order to train my data, should I run linear regression multiple times on training data? Is this what training a dataset means? I'm using `lm` function in R to do this. Here is my code:

```
smp_size <- floor(.7 * nrow(Boston))

set.seed(133)
train_boston <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Boston)), size=smp_size)
train_ind    <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Boston)), size=smp_size)
train_boston <- Boston[train_ind, ]
test_boston  <- Boston[-train_ind,]
nrow(train_boston)   # [1] 354
nrow(test_boston)    # [1] 152
train_boston.lm <- lm(lstat~medv, train_boston)
summary(train_boston.lm)
```

Comment: You probably mean "train [or fit] my model" -- the dataset isn't going to change.

Comment: Fitting the model multiple times will give you the same coefficients each time, assuming the training data are fixed and the fitting procedure is deterministic.  In that case, there's no point fitting more than once.  Could you add some code showing us what you've tried to do?

Comment: code added following your request

Comment: So in order to train my training dataset, I need to use lm functions with different number of rows every time? Is that what training a data set means?

Comment: You have `lstat` (a dichotomous variable) as your response, & you included `[logistic]` as a tag, so you seem to be aware that logistic regression is appropriate here. You should realize then that `lm()` is for OLS *linear models*. To fit a LR, you need to use `glm(, family=binomial)`.